# VB.NET Array with Double Bracket ()()

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, brackets

I came accross a double bracket after the variable name and I was wondering what does it mean.

What does the below mean?

```
Private orgIdField()() As String
```

I am just aware of;

```
Private orgIdField() As String
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a jagged array (an array of arrays). You can find more info at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_JaggedArrays).